# looking for the correct statistical test

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, linear-model, granger-causality

I am studying whether quality of sleep affects physical activity performances on the following day (or viceversa, i.e. physical activity affects the quality of sleep).

I measure several variables to assess quality of sleep and physical activity level.

These variables are measured in (a median of) 4 consecutive nights and days of different subjects.

My data looks like:

```
                                **subject 1** 

night_sleep_par_1_day1  night_sleep_par_2_day1  night_sleep_par_n_day1
night_sleep_par_1_day2  ...                     ...   
night_sleep_par_1_day3  ...                     ... 
night_sleep_par_1_day4  night_sleep_par_2_day4  night_sleep_par_n_day4


day_activity_par_1_day1  day_activity_par_2_day1  day_activity_par_n_day1
day_activity_par_1_day2  ...                     ...   
day_activity_par_1_day3  ...                     ... 
day_activity_par_1_day4  day_activity_par_2_day4  day_activity_par_n_day4

                                    ...

                                **subject n** 

night_sleep_par_1_day1  night_sleep_par_2_day1  night_sleep_par_n_day1
night_sleep_par_1_day2  ...                     ...   
night_sleep_par_1_day3  ...                     ... 
night_sleep_par_1_day4  night_sleep_par_2_day4  night_sleep_par_n_day4


day_activity_par_1_day1  day_activity_par_2_day1  day_activity_par_n_day1
day_activity_par_1_day2  ...                     ...   
day_activity_par_1_day3  ...                     ... 
day_activity_par_1_day4  day_activity_par_2_day4  day_activity_par_n_day4
```

notation: sleep_par_1_day1 is the value of the sleep parameter 1 during the first assessed day.

What is the  best test to study this kind of correlation?
In particular I would like to study whether one (or a set of) sleep parameters are correlated with one (or a set of) day activity parameters (but also the opposite could be true...i.e. quality of sleeps depends from the activity performed during the day).

Thanks in advance.

PS I could have some missing value...

Comment: Could you please describe your data in more detail? How are variables "quality of sleep" and "type of activity" assessed?

Comment: @Digio My dataset consist on variables measuring the quality of sleep and activity level during several consecutive nights and days. Each variable is a continuous (interval) variable that can assume any positive value. You can think about sleep variables as the time spent sleeping during the night, the number of time the subject woke up during the night, etc.

Comment: What are the maximum and minimum values for your two variables? If you consider your response variable (quality of sleep) as a continuous variable and group it by type of activity (i.e. consider activity as a qualitative variable), you will be able to look for statistically significant differences between those groups via ANOVA and post-hoc analysis. Can your type of activity take discrete values?

Comment: Yes I can consider activity as a discrete variable and perform ANOVA test. Would a repeated measure ANOVA fit better this problem? I should run first ANOVA grouping activity and the again grouping the quality of sleep. Is it correct?

Comment: I think it's the best tool for your scenario. But plain ANOVA won't suffice as you need to assess all pairwise differences between your groups. Are your sleep datasets (per group) normally distributed?

Comment: To add to that, you should run one-way ANOVA (once) on y~x where y is  quality of sleep and x is the activity group for that observation. In other words, y will contain all concatenated sleep observations and x will denote the activity group corresponding to every observation.